# Plot multiple data with DiscretePlot

Tags: maple

Currently, I'm plotting a single discrete function `f` known on a discrete set `t` using the following code:

```
t := Vector(3, [0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
f := Vector(3, [1, 2, 3])
DiscretePlot(t, f)
```

Now, suppose I've got a second function `g` known at the same set `t`. How can I plot `f` and `g` in the same plot?

Comment: This question is not appropriate for this site, because it is about how to use Maple, and not about mathematics. It would more suited to http://www.mapleprimes.com  or  http://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few different ways to accomplish that.

```
restart;
with(DynamicSystems):

t := Vector(3, [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]):

f := Vector(3, [1, 2, 3]):
g := Vector(3, [1, 4, 9]):
h := Vector(3, [1, 8, 27]):

plots:-display(
  DiscretePlot(t, f, color=red),
  DiscretePlot(t, g, color=green),
  DiscretePlot(t, h, color=blue)
);

col_list := [red,green,blue]:
dat_list := [f,g,h]:

plots:-display(zip((a,b)->DiscretePlot(t,a,color=b),
               dat_list, col_list));

plots:-display(seq(DiscretePlot(t, dat_list[i],
                                color=col_list[i]),
               i=1..3));
```